# SVG SMIL растущая линия как реализовать?

Tags: анимация, svg, animate

Доброй ночи уважаемые. Подскажите кто знает, как в SMIL анимации реализовать эффект плавного роста?
Вот на этой простой линии.

```css
.st4 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #B2091F;
  stroke-width: 8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 256 256" style="enable-background:new 0 0 256 256;" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<path id="myLine" class="st4" d="M 0,235 L 256,235" />

<animate
 xlink:href="#myLine"
 attributeName="d" 
    dur="1200ms" 
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 keyTimes="0;1"
 values="M  0,235
       L 256,235"
/>


</svg>
```

Если б через CSS то там через анимацию stroke-dashoffset и stroke-dasharray оно б реализовалось. Как это сделать в SMIL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ реализовать анимацию линии состоит в изменении координат "x2", "Y2" - конца линии,   с помощью команды -`<animate attributeName="x2"  dur="4s" values="25;175;25"` Координата "x2" увеличивается с 25 до 175 и обратно до 25

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
 <line  x1="25" y1="50"  x2="175" y2="50" stroke="orangered" style="stroke-linecap:round;" stroke-width="20" >
    <animate attributeName="x2"  dur="4s" values="25;175;25" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </line>
 </svg>
```

Во втором примере линия расположена по диагонали и изменяя координату конца линии "x2" заставляем её делать более сложные движения.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
 <line  x1="25" y1="175"  x2="175" y2="50" stroke="dodgerblue" style="stroke-linecap:round;" stroke-width="20" >
    <animate attributeName="x2"  dur="4s" values="25;175;25" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </line>

   </svg>
```

Одновременное изменение обоих координат "X2" и "Y2" конца линии, заставляет линию двигаться по диагонали.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
 <line  x1="25" y1="175"  x2="175" y2="25" stroke="violet" style="stroke-linecap:round;" stroke-width="20" >
    <animate attributeName="x2"  dur="4s" values="25;175;25" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 <animate attributeName="y2"  dur="4s" values="175;25;175" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </line>

   </svg>
```

Добавляем атрибут `stroke-dasharray` для оформления линии и неожиданно получаем ожившие сосиски :-)

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
 <line  x1="25" y1="175"  x2="175" y2="25" stroke="crimson" style="stroke-linecap:round; stroke-width:10; stroke-dasharray: 20 5 10 10;" >
    <animate attributeName="x2"  dur="3s" values="25;175;25" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 <animate attributeName="y2"  dur="3s" values="175;25;175" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
 </line> >

   </svg>
```

Анимация с использованием атрибутов: **`stroke-dasharray`** = "195"
     **`stroke-dashoffset`** ="195"  Цифра - "195" - это полная длина линии.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
 <path id="myLine" class="st4" d="M 5,100 L 200,100"  stroke="crimson" stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray= "195"
     stroke-dashoffset="195" >
  <animate  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  
         values="195;0;195" dur="4s" repeatCount="4"  fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear"/>
     </path>
  </svg>
```

Рисование треугольника

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
 <path id="myLine" class="st4" d="M 10 210 L 110 10 L 210 210 L10 210" fill="none"  stroke="crimson" stroke-width="10"   stroke-dasharray= "647"  stroke-dashoffset="647" >
  <animate id="p1"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  
         values="647;0; 647" dur="8s" repeatCount="3"  fill="freeze"  calcMode="linear"/>
 </path>
  </svg>
```

Анимация иконки "ОК" с помощью [рисования линии](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1253#more-1253). В этом примере работает две последовательные анимации. Вторая анимация - заполнение цветом контура, который был прорисован при первой анимации.
 Начало второй анимации достигается командой - `begin = "p1.end`, где `p1` - идентификатор первой анимации.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="94" height="94" viewBox="0 0 47 47"  >
       <circle fill="#4CAF50" cx="24" cy="24" r="21"/>
         <path class="path" fill= "none" stroke ="#CCFF90" stroke-width ="1.5" stroke-dasharray= "70.2" stroke-dashoffset="0" 
         d="M 34.6 14.6  L 21 28.2 L 15.4 22.6 L 12.6 25.4 L 21 33.8 L 37.4 17.4z">
         <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="1s;f1.end+0.4s" values="0;70.2;0;" dur="6s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced"/> 
         <animate id="f1" attributeName="fill" begin = "p1.end" values="#4CAF50; #CCFF90; #4CAF50" dur="2s" fill="freeze" /> 

         </path> 


    </svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно указывать значения `from` и `to`:

```css
.st4 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #B2091F;
  stroke-width: 8;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 256 256" style="enable-background:new 0 0 256 256;" xml:space="preserve">

<path id="myLine" class="st4" d="M 0,235 L 256,235" />

<animate
 xlink:href="#myLine"
 attributeName="d" 
  dur="1200ms" 
 repeatCount="indefinite"
 keyTimes="0;1"
  from = "M 0,235 L 0,235"
  to = "M 0,235 L 256,235"
  />


</svg>
```

[Больше про smil](http://css-live.ru/articles/rukovodstvo-po-svg-animaciyam-smil.html)